# Is there a way to launch bitcoin-core and have it shut down when synchronized?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

I use bitcoin core infrequently.  I don't want to have it running all the time, but I'm willing to (for now) devote disk space to having it stay current.  I'd like to be relatively current whenever I *do* start it up, without being weeks behind.

What I'd like to do is:

- Once a week or so, start bitcoin-core up.
- Have it shut down once it's caught up (I guess defined as "when the latest transaction is less than an hour old).

I know how to handle step one (via cron/launchd/etc).  What I don't know how to do is step 2: either having it terminate automatically, or using some kind of CLI-command to check the sync status every so often.

If the answer to this is "put in a feature request to bitcoin core", then I'd be looking for workarounds/alternate methods to use until that worked.

For the record, I'm on OSX, but in theory this question applies to all variants of the client.

Any ideas?

Comment: Bitcoin-core can never complete synchronising since every 8 - 10 min there's an new block.

Comment: Asker specified that he considers to be caught up when he's only one hour behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sleep for e.g. 10 minutes after you started bitcoind, and then  do the following:

1. `bitcoin-cli getblockcount`, which is the current height of the node
2. call `getpeerinfo`, parse the JSON, take the median of `startingheight` (how far these nodes are)
3. If difference < 10, stop bitcoind with `bitcoin-cli stop` and exit
4. Sleep 1 minute, repeat

Or use something like [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/21824/4948) to determine if the last known block is less than an hour old.