# How to figure out litecoind has finished synching the chain?

Tags: json-rpc, litecoin

I’d like to know what is the latest block number,
with bitcoind i’m using the rpc blockchaininfo and can read the inititalblockdownload that tells me if it’s synched, and the block number is also in the message.
How to do that with litecoind ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$ litecoin-cli getblockchaininfo`

Note: "There is no way for checking whether syncing is done, simply because it isn't known." See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/10443/60443